# Is there an efficient way to avoid repeated evaluation with mapValues?

Tags: scala

The `mapValues` method creates a new `Map` that modifies the results of queries to the original `Map` by applying the given function. If the same value is queried twice, the function passed to `mapValues` is called twice.

For example:

```
case class A(i: Int) {
  print("A")
}
case class B(a: A) {
  print("B")
}
case class C(b: B) {
  print("C")
}

val map = Map("One" -> 1)
  .mapValues(A)
  .mapValues(B)
  .mapValues(C)

val a = map.get("One")
val b = map.get("One")
```

This will print `ABCABC` because a new set of case classes is created each time the value is queried.

How can I efficiently make this into a concrete `Map` that has pre-computed the `mapValues` functions? Ideally I would like a mechanism that does nothing if the `Map` already has concrete values.

I know that I can call `map.map(identity)` but this would re-compute the index for the `Map` which seems inefficient. The same is true if the last `mapValues` is converted to a `map`.

The `view` method will turn a strict `Map` into a non-strict `Map`, but there does not seem to be a method to do the opposite.

Comment: in `2.13` method `mapValues` will be deprecated and later reimplemented as strict.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `force` on the view to force evaluation:

```
scala> val strictMap = map.view.force
ABCstrictMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,C] = Map(One -> C(B(A(1))))

scala> strictMap.get("One")
res1: Option[C] = Some(C(B(A(1))))

scala> strictMap.get("One")
res2: Option[C] = Some(C(B(A(1))))
```

I'd be careful about assuming that this will perform better than a simple `map`, though, and even if it does, the difference is likely to be negligible compared to the noise and the inconvenience if you need to cross-build for 2.11 or 2.12 and future Scala versions that will fix `mapValues` and change the view system entirely.

Comment: Thanks, that is an interesting option but, as you say, unlikely to be faster than `map(identity)`. I will watch the progress on the new library with great interest.